# [Tizen TV]How to get serial number of samsung tv

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I was trying to get the serial number of a TV with Tizen version 6.5, but it seems that only DUID is available on the system info API. Is there a way we can fetch the serial number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature which webapp can get serial number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official API document, there is no api to get the serial number of Samsung TV

(FYI, the serial value can be changed via Factory settings, so it isn't an unique value on real TV device).

In case you want to get an unique info for every single TV, you can consider to get the DUID or MAC address.

```
var _duid = webapis.productinfo.getDuid();

var _macAddress = webapis.network.getMac();
```

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/tizen-web-device-api-references/systeminfo-api.html